# Binding to two values

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Is it possible to bind a label content to two values. For eg, I want a single label whose content is displayed as below,
**UserName= Firstname, Lastname**

where Firstname and Lastname, both are values from database. If I would be using to labels I would bind as Content={Binding Firstname} for one and Content={Binding Lastname}
for another. But I want a single label to display both. Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}, {1}">
            <Binding Path="firstName" />
            <Binding Path="lastName"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```